# Habilitar o .htaccess no ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, htaccess

Estou usando o sistema ubuntu em meu PC e o meu apache parece que não reconhece o htaccess, nenhum, pois eu criei um .htaccess para o meu projeto só que ele não interpreta o que está no conteúdo. O conteúdo é o seguinte:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /FJU/

RewriteRule ^visualizar/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ pages/visualizar.php?p=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Infelizmente quando acesso por exemplo `http://localhost/FJU/relatorio` ele não exibe a página que quero, não envia o comando e o erro apresentado é:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /FJU/relatorio was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Tentei habilitado usando o comando **$ sudo a2enmod rewrite** e editar o arquivo do diretório **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default** para:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

Mas nada adiantou.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo.

## mod_rewrite

Você precisa habilitar o `mod_rewrite` (pode ser que ele já esteja habilitado, mas é bom verificar):

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

## htaccess

O caminho do arquivo padrão varia conforme sua versão do Ubuntu e Apache.

#### Ubuntu 13.04 ou inferior e Apache 2.2

Edite o arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` e troque a linha

```
AllowOverride None
```

Por:

```
AllowOverride All
```

#### Ubuntu 13.10 ou superior e Apache 2.4

Edite o arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` e procure pela linha `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`.

Adicione a regra para o diretório:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Não se esqueça de restartar o apache após aplicar as configurações:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

### Fontes:

- [askubuntu- Is this a correct way to enable htaccess in Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles)
- [How to enable mod_rewrite in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)

Comment: Esse post foi de grande ajuda, funcionou pra mim muito bem, obrigado.