# Como redirecionar o antigo domínio para o novo?

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de redirecionar o antigo domínio para o novo, no código atual está ocorrendo loop infinito.

Segue meu código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule (.*) http://novodominio.tk$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tá errado isso, falta a barra:

```apacheconf
  RewriteRule (.*) http://novodominio.tk$1 [R=301,L]
```

O certo é isso:

```apacheconf
 RewriteRule (.*) http://novodominio.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Recomendo que adicione uma regra pra impedir o redirecionamento infinito assim:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks

#verifica se já está no novo dominio (não adicione http: na frente)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !adota-me.tk$ [NC]

#redireciona
RewriteRule (.*) http://adota-me.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Uma dica, é preferível não usar o `IfModule` no caso do mod_rewrite apenas, pois se o servidor não tiver habilitado pra mod_rewrite então você não vai notar o erro e vai parecer que é um problema no .htaccess quando o problema é outro, se retirar o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` e `</IfModule>`, e após isto tentar rodar o .htaccess em um servidor com mod_rewrite desabilitado ele vai emitir o erro:

> Internal Error Server

Isso significa que precisa habilitar o mod_rewrite, então siga as instruções deste link:

- [Habilitar o .htaccess no ubuntu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30116/3635)

Ou entre em contato com o suporte da sua hospedagem

Comment: dá este erro agora  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes vou testar.

Comment: unica coisa diferente é Options +FollowSymLinks que eu nao coloquei pois caso eu coloque dá este erro   Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zetrFAx8

Comment: coloquei assim agora http://pastebin.com/jEBeQJAW  não tem erro mas nao direciona

Comment: rewrite.load esta na lista de arquivos de mods-enabled

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: esta a dar esse erro

Comment: ao fazer sudo a2enmod rewrite  aparece Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes apaga todo o conteudo do .htaccess e adiciona somente isso `RewriteEngine On` e me diz se ainda dá o erro "Internal error server"

Comment: sim dá esse erro

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes andei um pouco ausente, me chama no chat assim que possivel, não sei se resolveu o seu problema com o servidor